# JSON error at the end of the input

Tags: php, json

I have a question about JSON this time. I have created a script that manually outputs some database info into JSON (I have learned that php has a built in function for this, but I'm curious to find to learn something anyway). Currently, I'm getting the following error:

```
Parse error on line 68:
...         ]        }
----------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', ']'
```

Another validation gives me this error:

```
Error:Expecting closing ] at end[Code 22, Structure 157]
Error:Expecting closing } at end[Code 22, Structure 157]
```

My code (output generate by the php file) looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "X",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "y",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Z",
                            "size": 2500
                        },
                         //a bit cut out here
                        {
                            "name": "A",
                            "size": 2500
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "B",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "C",
                            "size": 2500
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "D",
                            "size": 2500
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "E",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "F",
                            "size": 2500
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "G",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "H",
                            "size": 2500
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

The last lines that generate the error (and d3.js not to work), but that is only the `}`.
Looking at notepad++ it appears to be nested properly, however, it keeps generating the errors. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://jsonlint.com/ for future issues, but it looks like you're missing a closing `]` and `}` (in that sequence) at very the end

Answer (score 0):

there is a couple of errors

1. you have commented `//a bit cut out here`, but JSON doesn't allow to do such things
2. you've messed up `]` (this is closing one of `"children": [`) and `}` (this is closing one of root object)

Comment: the comments is indeed not as it should be, that was only for this topic (otherwise it would have been very long). The second issue was indeed the problem. Thanks for your help!